# Internal lock with modified flat bolt?lock

Tags: electrical, lock, electronics

I have a surplus military case that I want to house a group of sensors inside and strapped to my car's roof rack. It's painted to avoid looking like anything but a typical cargo box. I'd like to add a pair of locks, but I'd like to do so with the locks mounted inside the walls and operated electronically.  The box is two more or less equal halves halved along the horizontal:

```
        [-----------------] Top
        [                 ]
Hinges &[-----------------] Center where box is split
        [                 ]
        [-----------------] Bottom
```

I'd like to take a pair of cabinet deadbolts, RFID control via an Arduino clone and change (or buy) the bolts so they are shaped in a way that I can put the receiving portion on the Top half and the powered half that moves on the bottom with the modified bolt being flat and shaped like a capital L, upside down and with the bottom attached to the existing bolt. This way the lock is in the way of the two sides opening and aside from the bolt sticking up when open nothing is obvious from outside the container.

Does anyone know if such a lock already exists or if there's a firm that will make on? As far as I can tell it's one of those options or having a pair CNC'd for me.

Comment: Just how secure do you need the whole thing to be? Do you want to hide the locks just to avoid attracting attention? ("Oh, that box has some sturdy locks on it, there must be something valuable in it.")

Comment: Exactly that and as the current default would seem to be a padlock and hasp on each side. But that might indicate there's potentially some nice equipment inside the box. If I can RFID (I forgot to add it's 3mm PP so it'll work well with RF) some kind of extended flat actuator that can be attached inside of the box's bottom and an open.. my lock terminology evades me here, but the slot fixture to accept the bolt) to the top I get discretion, low cost and decent actual protection. I'm tempted to get an internal electric bolt and its catch to connect internally on angle to work. Not ideal, though

Comment: why not use automotive trunk locks? unlike cabinet locks they wont shake open at highway speeds.  pick a vehicle that's popular with boy racers and there should be plenty of intact trunk locks at the junk-yard!